# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool when there is no records in the table in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have three table register, profile and uploaddoc tables. In the profile table, I am inserting the multiple records of related registered users and in uploaddoc ,i am inserting the multiple records of the profile. At the end, I am getting the latest records from the profile and uploaddoc table.

I used the below code to get the output on my page. I am passing the profile id to the uploaddoc table to get the related records.

```
function profile($reg_id,$pdo){

$query='SELECT * FROM `tbl_profile` WHERE  sp_id=(SELECT MAX(sp_id) FROM tbl_profile where reg_id ='.$reg_id.' GROUP BY reg_id order by reg_id DESC)  and is_active=1';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$data['profile']=$row;

if (!empty($row)) {
$query2='SELECT * FROM `tbl_uploadAll` WHERE u_id='.$row['sp_id'].' and is_active=1';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query2);
$stmt->execute();
$row2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
$data['uploadedDoc']=$row2;

}

return $data;
}
```

When the page loads then I am calling the profile function

```
<?php

$info=profile($_SESSION['reg_id'],$pdo);
$info['profile']; // getting single records
$info['uploadedDoc'] // getting the multiple records and displaying using for condition

?>
```

If the records are available on the profile and uploadedDoc then I am getting the data and it's working.

Now, My issue is, If there are no records in the profile and uploadedDoc table of related to register id then I am getting an error .

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

is there any way to solve this issue?

**connection.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "test";
$db="test";


$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
  }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Also, where is `$data` defined within the `profile` function?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato, I have $data['profile'] and $data['uploadedDoc'] and I am sending the data to the HTML. Do I need to defined like this $data[] ?

Comment: when I display the data like $info['profile']['name'] then I am getting the error

Comment: What happens if you var_dump($info)?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato, I am getting  array(1) { ["profile"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: Well then just add a `if($info['profile']){` before you echo `$info['profile']['name']` since profile is false you have no data to show

Comment: @AndreaOlivato,  I am displaying in data in the input field.                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php echo $info['profile']['name'];?>">

Comment: Yeah you can't do that. Or you'll get the error. You need to use `IF` before you do that.

Comment: I have 16 input fields on my page and if no data then display at least input field without an error

Comment: @AndreaOlivato, I am getting this error because ['profile'] is empty and its doesn't have ['profile']['name'] when there is no records

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php if($info['profile']) {echo $info['profile']['name'];}?>">

Comment: @AndreaOlivato,<?php if($info['profile']) {echo $info['profile']['name'];}?> Is it the correct way to use it? because I have 16 fields and I have to add this to all my fields.

Comment: Do I need to use something $info['profile']['name'] ?? ' '  or isset($info['profile']['name'])

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code:
$query='SELECT * FROM tbl_profile WHERE sp_id=(SELECT MAX(sp_id) FROM tbl_profile
where reg_id =? GROUP BY reg_id order by reg_id DESC) and is_active=?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$reg_id,$is_active]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$data['profile']=$row;
if (!empty($row)) {
$query2='SELECT * FROM tbl_uploadAll WHERE u_id=? and is_active=?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query2);
$stmt->execute([$sp_id,$is_active]);
$row2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
$data['uploadedDoc']=$row2;
}
return $data;
}

Comment: How this query will help me?

Comment: Did you test it?

Answer (score -1):

Try and reference $pdo again as $pdo = $this->pdo;
That's if you $pdo in the same class or use __construct

Comment: I am getting the $pdo from the database connection

Comment: connection.php code added in the question